# how to restrict textbox with specific format using asp.net regular expression validator

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have text which is binded to asp.net regular expression validation. I want max length of character as 13 and want to have format like `xx/xxxxx-xxxx`

This are valid formats

```
33/34567-1
33/12345-12
33/12345-123
33/12345-1234
```

I tried this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txt1_TextChanged" class="textNormal" MaxLength="13" Width="100"></asp:TextBox> (xx/xxxxx-xxxx)
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValidator1" runat="server"
                     ErrorMessage="Must be in format xx/xxxxx-xxxx" ValidationExpression="\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\d-\d{4}$"
                    ControlToValidate="txt1">Must be in format xx/xxxxx-xxxx</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

But its not working as i want. When i type `33/45678-12` then it throws validation error.
only one character after Last part after `-`is mandatory.

How to fix this?

Comment: Try using `\d\d\/\d{5}-\d{1,4}$` https://regex101.com/r/EJTmQC/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the 5 digits to `\d{5}` and match 1-4 digits at the end using `\d{1,4}` which will still have a  `MaxLength="13"`

```
ValidationExpression="\d\d\/\d{5}-\d{1,4}$"
```